# Having problems with reset to justify elements in flex containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox, reset

I'm using this [reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and I'm having problems using justify-content when this reset is enabled.
For example:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">2</div>
</div>
```

When this reset is enabled, the numbers keep one over another as columns, why and how I can have the same result as here but with the reset enable?

Comment: But I cannot see any reference of flex/justify-content in the reset css. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AbinThaha The problem is when I use the reset, I can't justify the content anymore using flexbox, I don't know why

Comment: @AbinThaha try to write this code with the reset and you will see what I'm saying

Comment: Just I checked your code with that above linked reset code.... Its worked fine for me. This is a [DEMO](https://jsbin.com/gozadoqala/edit?output)

Comment: @user3733831 It didn't work, the numbers 1 and 3 should be in the same row using justify-content

Comment: https://jsbin.com/fijuvobole/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: add the reset to your snippet or create another snippet with reset so we can compare

Comment: @TemaniAfif I will delete this post, I made another question, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489665/weird-behavior-using-a-reset-external-stylesheet

Comment: @AbinThaha I think the problem is with the external stylesheet, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489665/weird-behavior-using-a-reset-external-stylesheet