# Weird behavior using a separated reset stylesheet

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using this [reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) code, and the layout doesn't work as expected, when I use it as an external stylesheet instead of using only one stylesheet. In this way, I'm using only one stylesheet called styles.css

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/reset.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div>1 </div>
        <div> 2</div>

    </header>


</html>
```

CSS

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

The external stylesheet (I wrote exactly as I typed here):

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

The behavior:

[image]

So why is this happening? For me it should behave in the same way. The codes are exactly the same, the only difference is one is an external stylesheet and the other is the code of the reset.css written inside of the style.css. I'm just copying and paste, I don't think I made any mistake. So are there any different using one stylesheet instead than two?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple, I should have inserted the reset.css before the styles.css.